# How to add user defined icons in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I am a newbie to Ionic 2 and I want to use my own icons/image slices (like those i place in drawable folders in native android). Like in the list view I want to add an icon along with some text. I can found such examples nowhere. Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Following will be your Css file

```
.icon{
  background-image: url("../assets/icons/ic_icon.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

> Ionic 2 HTML code

```
<button ion-button color="secondary" clear>
<div class="icon">
              <p>Icon</p>
          </div>
  </button>
```

*This will work for you , in ionic 2, button tag is optional , it's there to add the tap effect*

Answer (score 1):

try **[icomoon](https://icomoon.io/)** service, which provides css files and fonts that easy include in project

Comment: I want to use my own image slices.

Comment: isn't there any way to do that in html?

Comment: Try this css :

.icon-<icon-name {
    background-image: url("<transparant-image-url");
    background-position: center center;
}